# How to split an image into polygons

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Similar to some coloring apps that fill a certain region with selected color when tapped, I would like to convert a png image to polygons which could be tapped in order to perform a certain action. An example picture is posted below.

[image]

For this example, I would like to implement the logic to divide the image into regions 1, 2, 3, and 4 (not necessarily in this order) so when the user taps on the upper-left rectangle, action1, for upper-right rectangle action2, for the ellipse actions, and for the rest action3 is executed.

Does anyone know how to do it by using SpriteKit?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to split the image into regions. Attach a tap gesture recognizer to your image view.

In the action of the tap gesture recognizer, take the coordinates of the tap and figure out which region it falls into.

Rectangular regions are really easy. You just see if the coordinates fall within the x/y bounds of the rectangle.

For more complex shapes, you can create `UIBezierPath` shapes and use the `UIBezierPath` `contains(_:)` method to see if the tap point falls in a particular path.

The simplest way to structure your code would be an array of structs each of which contains a `UIBezierPath` and a closure to invoke if a tap lands in that path. You can then invoke the closure when a tap lands in one of those paths.

Comment: But how to know in advance which region has been tapped without previously splitting the image to regions?

Comment: I explained that, step by step. The tap comes into the parent view. That view (probably a custom subclass of UIView) has code that looks at the coordinates of the tap, searches through it's array of paths, and picks the path that contains the tap.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out. I thought it applies in case the image is already split to regions.

Comment: If you have the image split into regions you can make each one a separate image view with it's own tap gesture recognizer, but that will only handle rectangular tap regions. For irregular shapes you'll have to use a different approach like bezier paths and the `contains(_:)` function.

Comment: I've done things like I describe in my answer and I know they work.